# Next.js and Node(express.js)

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

Help. I want to utilize the express server API in Next.js 13.4. The new version auto-generates folders, creating a 'src' folder which contains an 'app' folder. In the past, with React applications, I would create a 'server' folder which included 'controller', 'route', and 'models' folders along with a server.ts file. This aligned with the MVC (Model-View-Controller) pattern. How should I implement this structure in Next.js 13.4?

I tried to celebrate this folder inside app folder that is located in src folder but it won't help

Comment: Nextjs contains it own builtin server if you want to go fullstack. But if it does not give you the flexibility you want you can try using a [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server) or a diferent backend